# iPhone UPNP Port mapping

Tags: iphone, upnp, portforwarding

Has anyone found a method to port forward an internal IP with iOS.

Note: Have tried CyberLink, Platinum, MiniUPNP, upnpx, TCMPortMapper with out success.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DNSServiceNATPortMappingCreate() in `usr/include/dns_sd.h` of the iOS SDK.